# obfuscate password with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex to obfuscate the password

```
myString.replaceAll(
    "<.{1,}:Password>.{1,}</.{1,}:Password>",
    "<!--<Password></Password> Removed-->");
```

When myString contains the following line it successfully obfuscates the password

```
<abc:Password>myPassword</abc:Password>
```

But if myString contains the xml without schema prefix i.e

```
<Password>myPassword</Password> it does not obfuscate the password.
```

How to extend the existing regex so that it processes both cases?

Comment: How about using `([a-z]*:)?` instead of `.{1,}:`?

Comment: You see why regular expressions are not the right tool to process XML?

Comment: What is the goal here?  Do you want to display an obfuscated password, or are you planning to store this password somewhere?  In the former case, why not just use `*****` or something like that?

Comment: Expanding on Henry's comment: What if your XML contained multiple `<abc:Password>whatever</abc:Password>`? What if it was nested? There might be cases where a regex doesn't match 100% (false positives or negatives) so unless you really know what you'll get you should note [that _regular_ expressions are no good fit for _irregular_ languages like XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @Thomas In my case there will be only one password entry in the entire xml string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are specifying the range of the number of expected characters, by using curly brackets. (`{1,}`)

Instead, you can either `+` or `*` to represent "one or more" (`+`) or "zero or more" (`*`) of the previous character. In other words, `*` is similar to `{0,}`, while `+` is the same as `{1,}`. In addition, you can use `?` to represent "zero or one", similar to `{0,1}`.

Using that knowledge, we can look for character(s) followed by a colon in front of the name of the element (`Password`), using this pattern:

```
.+:
```

We can then put that inside of a non-capturing group, by putting it inside a set of brackets with a `?:` in front (to make it non-capturing), and have it look for zero-or-more instances of it.

```
(?:.+:)?
```

Thus, your string could change to:

```
<(?:.+:)?Password>.+</(?:.+:)?Password>
```

Comment: Note that `(?:.+:+)*` might kill your regex engine in some cases (see [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) or [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS))

Comment: @Thomas Good point, thank you. The use of `*` was incorrect anyway; it should have been `?`.